# Restful WebService to get different attachments from a database in Eclipse

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, web-services

i have to write restful web-service in eclipse using jersey where i have to get different   files(.jpeg,.PDF,.docs etc..) from my database.. it should get the file and it contents too.. so that i can use this web-service in html with ajax to call web-service

code i have done so far..

```
@POST
@Path("/info/{username}/{projectid}")
@Produces("application/json")
public LinkedList<Statusis> responseMsg2(@PathParam("username") String uname, @PathParam("projectid") String pid ) throws SQLException {
    Map<String, Statusis> status = new HashMap<String, Statusis>();
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://servername:1433;databaseName=AMIS_TEST;user=xyz;password=****@123");
        String query = "usp_get_project_escalatedissues '" + uname + "' , '"  + pid  +"'";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
         if(rs!=null)
            {
        int count = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            Statusis statusis = new Statusis();
            statusis.setQueryID(rs.getString(1));
            statusis.setTitle(rs.getString(2));
            statusis.setIssueDescription(rs.getString(3));
            statusis.setClarificationId(rs.getString(4));
            status.put(statusis.getQueryID()+count,statusis);
            count++;
        }
            }
            else
            {
           return null;
            }
    } catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + err);
    } finally {
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    Response.ok().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
    return new LinkedList<Statusis>(status.values());

}
```

AJAX CALL IS:

```
$.ajax({
            url:serviceurl1 +'/' +uname + '/' +selctedprjt ,
             type: 'POST',            
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: 'json', 
             async : true,
            crossDomain: true,       
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Web service call succeeded." );
            $("#issuestable tbody tr").remove();
        if(data.status.length != undefined)
         {
             $.each(data.status, function (key, value)
              {
 $("#issuestable").append('<tbody><tr><td>'+value.queryID+'</td><td>'+value.title +'</td></tr></tbody>'); 
}else

  {
        //alert("in else");
}
  },
        error: function (error) 
        { 
         alert('ERROR has occurred!');
         alert(JSON.stringify(error))
        }
    })  

    });
```

I HAVE TWO FILES .PDF AND .JEPG files in my database procedure i used returns these files..
can any one tell me how to get them in my webservice along with fields i am retreiving

Comment: You need to flesh out the question. What have you done so far? Do you have code to show? Where are the files stored? What is the database holding? etc.

Comment: added the code plz look in to it.. @Catchwa

Comment: PDF data should be transferable as a response of a rest-ful request just fine.

Set the correct content type and transfer the binary content of the PDF.

Nothing special about it.

    What are you doing right now? Are you using an library?
    Describe your "unexepected results".
    Describe your "expression error"

Basically, you need to provide a lot more details.

Comment: when u are sending pdf how you can set content tpe as json.

Comment: I DIDNT ADD still.. just trying to add files from database.. dont know how to send along with json data